# importing one ml file into another

Tags: module, compilation, ocaml, interpreter, ml

I have an `interpreter.ml` file that contains an interpreter and some `type` definitions.

I've developed some test batteries to check if the interpreter works well or not.

When I put the functions I use to test the behaviour of the interpreter in the same file of the interpreter all works well, but if I try to use a different file for the tests (let's say `tests.ml`) it did not load the interpreter functions and definitions.

the `interpreter.ml` and `tests.ml` are in the same folder

I tried both with `open Interpreter` and `#use "./interpreter.ml"` from inside `tests.ml` but it wont compile nor shut down the warnings in the IDE (kind of...I'm using Visual Studio Code on MacOs )

I've already tried to follow the [official documentation](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/modules.html) but it won't compile with `ocamlopt -c tests.ml`

Comment: If I understand correctly, your program + test is splitted into 2 source files, and you try to compile those 2 files to get one executable that will perform the test. Is that correct ? To ease the compile process, did you use ocamlbuild ?

Comment: Alternatively, you could also use cppo that implements a preprocessor like cpp ; you can use it to include some file.

Comment: @PierreG. You understood well. I did not use ocamlbuild because I'm new to ocaml and the project is made just by two files and it didn't seemed necessary to use it

Comment: to keep simple : ocamlc -o exe test.ml interpreter.ml shall work. And in test.ml : open Interpreter. With ocamlbuild : ocamlbuild test.native shall be enough (ocamlbuild take care of dependency).

Comment: Is it possible to do something **like** in C (`#include"path/of/the/file.ml`) and import all the definitions of interpreter.ml into tests.ml?

Comment: see my 2nd comment :) cppo can  allow you to include a file. But in my view, you ought better to make files separated.

Comment: @PierreG. I saw it, but I need something that works without "extra software" since it is an assignment for the University. When I try with `ocamlc -o exe test.ml interpreter.ml` it gives me the error 
`File "tests.ml", line 1, characters 5-16:
Error: Unbound module Interpreter`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133155/discussion-between-pierre-g-and-gerardo-zinno).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of discussions, the executable is obtained by compiling the 2 files `test.ml` & `interpreter.ml` in the right order (`test.ml` relies on objects defined in `interpreter.ml`; as a consequence `test.ml` has to reference to interpreter objects either via the clause `open Interpreter` or by prefixing all relevant items with `Interpreter` ):

> ```
>  ocamlc -o exec interpreter.ml test.ml
> ```

`ocamlbuild` is easier as it resolves by itself the dependencies:
The following command:

> ```
>  ocamlbuild test.native
> ```

will produce the executable.